# How to correctly subclass UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gesture-recognition

I have gone through the documentation:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130309051214/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2

I am trying to implement the check mark example shown in the documentation and I can't because the compiler shows a bunch of warnings about the `[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event]` call, which is recommended by the documentation.

Where's the full example to learn how to correctly subclass for implementing a custom gesture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the following [WWDC 2010 Session Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/) extremely useful:

- Session 120 - Simplifying Touch Event Handling with Gesture Recognizers ([pdf](https://download.developer.apple.com/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/120__simplifying_touch_event_handling_with_gesture_recognizers.pdf))
- Session 121 - Advanced Gesture Recognition ([pdf](http://adcdownload.apple.com/wwdc_2010/wwdc_2010_video_assets__pdfs/121__advanced_gesture_recognition.pdf))

To access these videos you must login at https://developer.apple.com.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot - I had skipped the "Advanced..." previously. I don't seem be able to download the source, any idea on why?

Comment: try to navigate there by ur own. I posted the links for HD. U could try SD. http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: My itunes window was too small, I found it. Thanks! Where's the advanced sample for the gestures? I see only touches and simple gestures in the zip.

Comment: I've fixed some links, but I don't know how to fix the link to sample codes of WWDC 2010 which may have been unpublished by Apple in favor of newer videos/sessions.

Comment: Well, I've found the pdf, that's probably the best we can get now.