# Detecting circular touch iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

i want to detect when user uses one finger to make a circular motion on a UIView

any help will be appreciated

Comment: see this link http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ndrotator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's bad practice to answer with a bunch of links. But so is reinventing the wheel.

Take a look at:

[Recognising a circle gesture to drop an annotation, how to detect circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842892/recognising-a-circle-gesture-to-drop-an-annotation-how-to-detect-circle)

[How to detect a circle motion with UIGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842080/how-to-detect-a-circle-motion-with-uigesturerecognizer)

[How to detect circular gesture via Gesture Recognizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600690/how-to-detect-circular-gesture-via-gesture-recognizer)

All the linked questions include accepted answers.

Comment: you should close the question for duplicate. Not copy paste some links that are on stack.

Comment: @AlexTerente: i think sometimes a list of 80% 'duplicates' is much more informative (for OP and later for others) and useful that simply closing question as a duplicate. Each of these 'duplicates' holds a number of further references. If they ALL could be joined under one meta-question: then i'd agree

Answer (score 1):

Subclass youe UIView and implement

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

In touch moved you get the new touch points and you can see if the touch points are on a circle arc.

Comment: hehe i know that :), how can i determine from the points i get that the user is moving in a circle