# recognize pattern on ios

Tags: ios, design-patterns, gesture-recognition

Does anyone know a good touch pattern recognition library? How is it generally done? I would like to have the entire IOS device as an input device. For example, if someone draws a big heart on the screen, we are going to the favorites page. Somehow I need to know someone drew a big heart on the screen.

Thanks, 
Ross

Comment: I'd love to know this too! Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [MultistrokeGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/britg/MultistrokeGestureRecognizer-iOS)  library on GitHub that looks promising.  Looks like its a matter of running the Shape Editor and exporting the strokes as a JSON array of points. This should be enough to get you started.

If you need more resources I would take a look at the two WWDC videos on gesture recognizers from 2010 as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4074583/1382210) SO answer.

Here's a link to the 2011 WWDC multi-touch video which may be of some help to you also.

[Session 118 - Making the Most of Multi-Touch on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.8270634034.08270634040.8367260921?i=1527940296)

Answer (score 2):

See [Creating Custom Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW2).

For what it's worth, having to draw a heart to get to your favourites sounds like an abysmal user interface.  Don't focus on the potential for the technology so much you forget about the *people*.

Comment: I agree, i think heart is a bit complicated. Swipes and tap-long holds are much more easier to utilize. If you really want to implement a custom gesture recognizer, I'd say the most extreme should be circles or tick(check) marks.